# OCaml - Traversing a list without recursion

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to write following code without recursion:

```
let rec traverse lst =
  match lst with
  | a::b::t ->
      (* Something that return None*)
      traverse (b::t)
  | _ -> ()
```

How to do it in imperative way ?

Comment: Note that None is an Ocaml value of type 'a option that is different from unit ( i.e. () ). Thus, your comment (* Something that return None*) is not correct !

Answer (score 1):

In an imperative way:

```
let traverse li =
  let state = ref li in
  while !state <> [] do
    let x = List.hd !state in
    state := List.tl !state;
    (* do whatever you want *)
  done
```

If you need to access the second element of the list, just use the appropriate `List.hd` call. But you may need to check that the list isn't empty first.

I see no reason to do that this way, which is heavier, less efficient and less flexible than a recursive loop.

Comment: Ok, but when I'm trying to write a recursion (As  I wrote i previous post) I get an error.

Comment: I haven't seen your previous post, but maybe you should try harder?